# Can input arguments be passed to an httpyac file?

Tags: rest, http, request, command-line-arguments

I am looking to pass an input argument from the command line to an httpyac file. Specifically, I want to call the httpyac file in such a way that I can pass the id argument and access it within the httpyac file. Here's an example of how I am currently calling the httpyac file:

```bash
httpyac ./seeds/fill.http --all --var id=0
```

Within the fill.http file, I am attempting to retrieve the id argument using the following syntax:

```http
{{+
  exports.defaultHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
}}

@id={{$0}}
```

I would appreciate guidance on how to properly structure this call and retrieve the taskId argument within the .http file.